# Multiple values in to the HTML <select> Tag

Tags: jquery, wordpress, elementor

I am  trying to show and hide Elementor sections with a

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery('#kategorije').change(function(){
      jQuery('.usluge).hide();
      jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

I was wondering is it possible to add multiple selection into the   HTML  Tag

```
<Select id="kategorije">
 <option value="web"; "web2";"web3">Websajt</option>
```

Screenshots

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGVvs.jpg)
[CSS ID and CSS classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3QqL.jpg)

http://propersoft.rs/about/

Comment: Sorry I might have misunderstood, you want to have multiple ids shown from a single select option?

Comment: Updated with a second example that would cover that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install the plugin that allowed me to insert the custom JS to the page it self

Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Add event listener to select
jQuery('#kategorijeSingle').change(function() {
// Hide elements with class usluge
jQuery('.usluge').hide();
if (jQuery(this).val() == "ALL"){
jQuery('.usluge').show();
}else{
// Show elements with selected class
jQuery('.' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The example below will start with all items hidden (using a `CSS` class), and then show one after being selected. Change the selected option will hide the previous and show the newly selected one. You can apply the class to multiple elements.

If you really want to use ; separated `id` then I have created a second `select` demo where the value of the select option is split and then this array is cycled through, showing each element in turn.

The code is fully commented.

Let me know if this wasn't what you wanted.

---

```js
// Add event listener to select
$('#kategorijeSingle').change(function() {

  // Hide elements with class usluge
  $('.usluge').hide();

  // Show elements with selected class
  $('.' + $(this).val()).show();

  // If you just want a single div to be shown using the id then uncomment the line below
  // $('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();

});

// Add event listener to select for ID
$('#kategorijeID').change(function() {

  // Hide elements with class usluge
  $('.uslugeID').hide();

  // Get IDs, split by ;
  ids = $(this).val().split(";");

// Cycle through each ID and show
  ids.forEach(function(id) {
    $('#' + id).show();
  })

});
```

```css
.usluge,
.uslugeID {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="kategorijeSingle">
  <option value="web1">Websajt 1</option>
  <option value="web2">Websajt 2</option>
  <option value="web3">Websajt 3</option>
</select>

<div id="web1" class="usluge web1">
  web1
</div>
<div id="web1second" class="usluge web1">
  web1 second
</div>
<div id="web2" class="usluge web2">
  web2
</div>
<div id="web3" class="usluge web3">
  web3
</div>

<hr>

<select id="kategorijeID">
  <option value="webID1">Websajt 1</option>
  <option value="webID2">Websajt 2</option>
  <option value="webID3">Websajt 3</option>
  <option value="webID1;webID3">Websajt 1 and 3</option>
</select>

<div id="webID1" class="uslugeID">
  web1
</div>
<div id="webID2" class="uslugeID">
  web2
</div>
<div id="webID3" class="uslugeID">
  web3
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Oliver thanks for your quick reply. I did exactly what you told me and this is still not working for me. Please check the updated Question with the screenshot attached.Thanks